# No funciona SELECT a una base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, php5

Estoy intentando hacer un login sencillo. La idea es que busque en la base de datos el usuario y la contraseña.

El caso es que tengo puesto un `SELECT` que debería coger las filas con nombre y usuario que coinciden con las que ha introducido el usuario previamente.

El `SELECT` no me coge ninguna fila, es decir, no es culpa del `SELECT` sino de la sentencia para conectarse a la base de datos.

Codigo `validar.php`, donde ocurre el fallo:

```
<?php
        include 'serv.php';
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){
            $usuario = $_POST['user'];
            $pw = $_POST['pw'];
            $log = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM noticiasBD WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'");
            echo "tenemos: $log";
            echo '<script> alert("tenemos: $log");</script>';

            if (mysqli_num_rows($log)>0) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($log);
                $_SESSION["user"] = $row['user']; 
                echo 'Iniciando sesión para '.$_SESSION['user'].' <p>';
                echo '<script> window.location="panel.php"; </script>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<script> alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");</script>';
                echo '<script> window.location="index.php"; </script>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Aquí tengo el formulario donde llamo a `validad.php`. Se llama `index.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'serv.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
echo '<script> window.location="panel.php"; </script>';
}
?>

<h1 class="h1" style="color:white">Login</h1>
        <form method="post" action="validar.php">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" autocomplete="off" required><br><br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pw" autocomplete="off" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="login" value="Entrar">
        </form>
```

Y me conecto a la base de datos a partir de `serv.php`, el cual no da fallo:

```
<?php
$conect = mysqli_connect('localhost', '--', '--', 'c1jormacolBD')
  or die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

Imagen de phpMyAdmin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se conecta bien a la base de datos pero no a la tabla en cuestión.

Comment: Podrías indicar si te da algun error "Table noticiasBD" not found o algo similar? Las passwords las tienes en texto plano?

Comment: Al llamar a [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), te esta faltando indicar el [`link`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), esto debería mostrar un error como resultado. ¿Estas seguro que esta entrando al `if(isset($_POST['login']))`? *PD*: Tu código es susceptible a `inyección sql`, te recomiendo que leas [este articulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: "SELECT * FROM noticiasBD"
eso es una tabla o una base?
no deberia ser "FROM noticiasBD.usuarios" ? Sí queres adjunta una caputa de tu BD

Comment: @j0se , he mirado si hay algun tipo de error en la carpeta log, error.log, y no da ningun tipo de error.

Comment: @Marcos Si entra en el isset, puesto que puedo ver como el echo imprime tenemos: 0

Comment: @Nico he editado la publicación para que puedas ver la base de datos. La tabla se llama así, noticiasBD.

Comment: Podrias probar lo que te dice @Marcos de pasarle el link ? Mira el enlace que te puso

Comment: @Marcos he añadido el archivo donde hago el msqli_connect a mi base de datos

Comment: trata de probar quitando esta instruccion `if(isset($_POST['login'])){`

Comment: y cambia la consulta por `SELECT user, pw FROM noticiasBD WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'"`

Comment: @LuisFernando he borrado el isset y cambiado la sentencia y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: pero te tira errores? te muestra el Echo de usuario y contraseña incorrecta?

Comment: Acabo de ejecutarlo sin el isset y con la sentencia así y me ha dado estos errores: mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/clients/client8/web21/web/validar.php on line 18, referer: 
 mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/clients/client8/web21/web/validar.php on line 22, referer:

Comment: @CMorillo ya he redactado una respuesta, espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El principal problema que estás sufriendo es no pasar la conexión obtenida con [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/mysqli-connect) a la función [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli-query):

```
$log = mysqli_query($conect, "
  SELECT *
  FROM noticiasBD
  WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'
");
```

Además, estás olvidando usar [`session_start`](http://php.net/session-start) para iniciar las sesiones, sin embargo tratas de usarlas para almacenar el usuario logueado en:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $row['user'];
```

Según el error que comentas en tu edición es probable que en otra parte del código (no coinciden los números de línea, es probable que hayas omitido código) se haya iniciado sesión, así que podemos usar [`session_status`](http://php.net/session-status) para saber si se hizo o no:

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_DISABLED) {
  session_start();
}
```

Estás obteniendo el resultado con la función `mysql_fetch_array` en vez de [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-row) y, además, obtendrías valores con índice numérico (`$row[0]`, `$row[1]`), no asociativos (`$row['user']`, `$row['pw']`):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($log);
```

Por último, recordarte **LA IMPORTANCIA DE PROTEGERTE CONTRA [INYECCIÓN SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)** haciendo uso de [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysqli-real-escape-string).

Éste sería tu código arreglado:

```
<?php
/* Si vamos a usar sesiones debemos iniciarlas aquí también */
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_DISABLED) {
  session_start();
} 
include 'serv.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    /* ¡¡NO OLIVIDES hacer esto para evitar inyección SQL!!! */
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $_POST['user']);
    $pw = mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $_POST['pw']);
    $log = mysqli_query($conect, "
      SELECT *
      FROM noticiasBD
      WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'
    ");
    /* Debemos comprobar si hubo un fallo en la consulta */
    if ($log === false) {
        die('ERROR SQL: ' . mysqli_error($conect));
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($log);
    if ($row !== false) {

        /* Esto no funciona sin el "session_start()" inicial */
        $_SESSION["user"] = $row['user'];
        echo '<p>Iniciando sesión para ' .
          htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user']) . '</p>';
        echo '<script> window.location="panel.php"; </script>';
        /* Probablemente esto sea mejor que javascript */
        header('Location: panel.php');
    } else {
        echo '<script> alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");</script>';
        echo '<script> window.location="index.php"; </script>';
    }
}
```

Además, he agregado control de error para gestionar errores SQL en la consulta y he detectado si el usuario existe o no obteniendo el resultado de la consulta con [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/mysqli-fetch-assoc) (valdrá `true` si se encontró o `false`, no hay más registros, si no fue así).

Por último, es una mala práctica guardar claves en texto plano en la base de datos. Si alguien consigue acceder a esos datos (por lo pronto ya estabas permitiendo que lo hicieran por sufrir un bug de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)) expondrías los datos de acceso y pondrías muy fácil suplantar las identidades de tus clientes.

Comment: tu sugerencia ha funcionado perfectamente, pero me ha surgido un nuevo problema. Después de validad.php le redirecciono a panel.php pero no es capaz de hacerlo, es como si la sesión estuviera abierta o hay algun error de parentesis. Acabo de editar la pregunta original. Agradeceria que le echara un vistazo.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia de las contraseñas, buscaré información para mejorarlo

Comment: PD: Acabo de detectar un error! has usado `mysql_fetch_array` en vez de `mysqli_fetch_array`, pero ya no es necesario porque hice un `fetch_assoc` antes. Edito mi respuesta para corregirlo.

Comment: Ya está corregido. Espero que ahora te funcione perfecto :)

Comment: Muy buen aporte, funciona perfecto, ya no me hará falta crear un hilo nuevo